# Python pandas - blank out entire cell if part of text matches pattern

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

Is it possible to blank out the entire content of a cell in a csv column if some of it's text matches a pattern list, and then output the result to a csv?  I can replace the matched text with blank but would like to replace the whole cell with blank (NOT deleting the row).

csv raw data looks like this:

```
date   id  subject                        description
9/1/19 342 New customer message 5:23 p.m. blah blah blah
9/4/19 356 need more info                 blah blah blah
9/7/19 378 SCRUBBED review                blah blah blah


import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Documents/sample.csv', 'r', encoding = 'ISO-8859-1', 
delimiter=',', usecols=[2])
pattern = '|'.join(['SCRUBBED','New customer message’, 'HELLO'])
df['subject'] = df['subject'].str.replace(pattern, '')
df.to_csv('C:/Documents/sample_removed.csv', encoding = 'ISO-8859-1', index=False)
```

Expected result is:

```
date   id  subject        description
9/1/19 342                blah blah blah
9/4/19 356 need more info blah blah blah
9/7/19 378                blah blah blah
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is with your regex. If you replace the line:

```
pattern = '|'.join(['SCRUBBED','New customer message’, 'HELLO'])
```

with:

```
pattern = '.*' + '.*|.*'.join(['SCRUBBED','New customer message’, 'HELLO']) + '.*'
```

It should work. str.replace will only replace the matched part of string, by adding .* to the front and end of your target text it will now match the whole cell (this might do unwanted things like replace the line "OTHELLO" with "" since it contains "HELLO", in this case you need to think more carefully about your regex).

Comment: Thanks @the_Martian! Any idea how to output all columns to the output csv? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains) to create a [mask](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) that you can then index into to make your replacements.

Indexing with NaN values will not work, so you could replace NaN values in the column first with `''` as a null value to ensure the column is a string. This way `str.contains` will only produce boolean values
that can be used with indexing.

```
df['subject'] = df['subject'].fillna('')
is_match = df['subject'].str.contains(pattern, regex=True)
df['subject'][is_match] = ''
```

An alternative approach would to not fill NaN values in the dataframe but instead alter the mask NaN values to either `False` or `True` depending on whether you want to leave NaN or replace it with the empty string respectively.

```
is_match = df['subject'].str.contains(pattern, regex=True)
df['subject'][is_match.fillna(True or False)] = ''
```

Regardless of the approach, to save the cleaned data, just use the `to_csv` method.

```
df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks @MattEding!  The code resulted in this error when I tried it: ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values.  Any idea how to get pass it?  Also, is it possible to output all columns to the output csv? Thanks.